# Compiler error ASP.NET MVC CS1525

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I have just started up a new project and seem to be getting a compiler error from one of the files generated by Visual Studio. This view is accessible and readable by the current solution and I'm not quite sure how to go about solving this.

[image: Error received]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message states that you have a malplaced "=" inside the "Index.cshtml"-file. Find it and remove/replace it and it should be ok!

Comment: "@firstItemOfSlideshow_Caption = false;" is the element causing the problem. Exactly why this element is causing trouble I can't tell without seeing the whole code Project. But that is a starting Point.

Comment: Thanks very much, ill have a thorough look.